# Deleting the minimum element of the final heap

Tags: tree, heap

I currently have the following mimimum heap tree:

```
        2 
   3        5
 4   8     6 10
9 7
```

I'm asked to 'delete the minimum element of the final heap'. Would the result be as follows or am I missing something? I might be missing something because this is way too easy.

```
          2 
   3        5
 4   8     6 10
9
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you find 7? The final heap is the whole heap, and its minimum is 2. The minimum of a min-heap is always at its top.

Now, try to find the solution by yourself.